# How to join and union at the same time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm sure this has a simple solution but I'm struggling to find it.

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  "name" VARCHAR(1),
  "id" INTEGER,
  "data1" VARCHAR(2)
);

INSERT INTO t1
  ("name", "id", "data1")
VALUES
  ('a', '1', 'a1'),
  ('d', '1', 'd1');
  
  

CREATE TABLE t2 (
  "name" VARCHAR(1),
  "id" INTEGER,
  "data2" VARCHAR(2)
);

INSERT INTO t2
  ("name", "id", "data2")
VALUES
  ('d', '1', 'd2'),
  ('k', '1', 'k2');
```

I want this final combined table:

```
| name | id  | data1 | data2 |
| ---- | --- | ----- | ----- |
| a    | 1   | a1    |       |
| d    | 1   | d1    | d2    |
| k    | 1   |       | k2    |
```

Things I've tried:

Do a union

```
select 
  t1.name,
  t1.id,
  t1.data1,
  NULL as data2
from t1
union 
select 
  t2.name,
  t2.id,
  NULL as data1,
  t2.data2
from t2

| name | id  | data1 | data2 |
| ---- | --- | ----- | ----- |
| a    | 1   | a1    |       |
| d    | 1   | d1    |       |
| d    | 1   |       | d2    |
| k    | 1   |       | k2    |
```

Do a full join

```
select * from t1
full join t2 on t2.id = t1.id 
     and t2.name = t1.name;

| name | id  | data1 | name | id  | data2 |
| ---- | --- | ----- | ---- | --- | ----- |
| a    | 1   | a1    |      |     |       |
| d    | 1   | d1    | d    | 1   | d2    |
|      |     |       | k    | 1   | k2    |
```

The answer is somewhere in between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a [`FULL OUTER JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-table-expressions.html):

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.name, t2.name) AS name,
       COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) AS id,
       t1.data1,
       t2.data2
FROM t1
FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON t2.name = t1.name
```

Output:

```
name    id  data1   data2
a       1   a1      null
d       1   d1      d2
k       1   null    k2
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2KiXuymFsgToNbr7HbFxfX/0)

Comment: And `OUTER` is implied when using `LEFT`, `RIGHT` or `FULL` 

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want a `full join`:

```
select *
from t1 full join
     t2
     using (name, id);
```

Comment: Huh! So simple. I think I need to understand better the difference between using `ON` and `USING`. Or is there an equivalent solution using `ON`?

Comment: Found it. See my answer.

Comment: @nachocab . . . This was the first answer.  I'm surprised you didn't accept it.

Comment: It was a tough call, but I ended up using Nick's approach because I can't always rely on t1 and t2 having the same column names (which I think is the requirement for `USING`)

Comment: @nachocab . . . But they have the same column names in your question, which is why I used `using`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Gordon and Nick for your answers.

I checked the documentation and found an even shorter variation:

```
select * 
from t1 
natural full join t2;
```

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN)

> Furthermore, the output of `JOIN USING` suppresses redundant columns: there is no need to print both of the matched columns, since they must have equal values.
> While `JOIN ON` produces all columns from T1 followed by all columns from T2, `JOIN USING` produces one output column for each of the listed column pairs (in the listed order), followed by any remaining columns from T1, followed by any remaining columns from T2.